# WebWorker - Transferring an array which contains objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, web-worker, arraybuffer

I have an array which I need to transfer from a WebWorker back to the main thread. As far as I know, only ArrayBuffers and TypedArrays are transferable and anything else is copied instead of transferred.

Problem I'm having is the array contains objects, so I'm not sure how to transfer them (which is needed due to the huge size).

For example assume I have:

```
function something() {
    this.x = 1;
    this.y = 2;
    this.z = 3;
}

var array = [];
for (var x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
    array[x] = new something();
}
```

Is there a way I can convert the array to an ArrayBuffer, transfer it then convert it back?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Consider posting for each element of the array (object?) when the object is created. Then put it in an array in the onmessage handler.

```
function something() {
    this.x = 1;
    this.y = 2;
    this.z = 3;
}

var array = [];
for (var x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
    postMessage(new something());
}
```

This should work for simple objects, like the one in the sample but you will have to test the boundaries.

> Data passed between the main page and workers are copied, not shared.
>   Objects are serialized as they're handed to the worker, and
>   subsequently, de-serialized on the other end. The page and worker do
>   not share the same instance, so the end result is that a duplicate is
>   created on each end. Most browsers implement this feature as
>   structured cloning.

[MDN: Passing Data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers#Passing_data)